# Cross-classification of imagery from several regions in GEE

Tags: javascript, beginner, time-limit-exceeded, google-earth-engine

For a project I want to do the following:

1. Use imagery from 17 different regions in Europe to train 17 RF classifiers
2. Use those 17 classifiers to classify each of the regions

It will be a multi-temporal classification, using greenest pixel values of 14-day time intervals from a total time range of 2018-04-01 to 2018-10-31.

The code, as printed below, works. As I am just getting started working with Google Earth Engine - i.e. GEE, I am sure there are things to improve. The code only includes 2 of the 17 regions for now, because that is how it does not time out. As soon as I include all of the regions, the calculations takes too long and eventually times out. So I need to improve my code to make it less computationally intensive.

```
//================================================================
// Data preparation:

// Define the regions of interest (ROIs) as a feature collection
var roi = regions;

// Define a list of region names
var regionNames = ['LVha-1', 'LVha-2'];

// add image collection
var S2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
  .filterDate('2018-04-01', '2018-10-31')
  .filterBounds(geometry)
  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 30));

//function to calculate NDVI
function addNDVI(image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B8','B4'])
  return image.addBands(ndvi.rename('NDVI'));
}

// map function over imageCollection
var NDVI_S2 = S2.map(addNDVI).select(['NDVI']);

//subset imageCollection by date range and composite greenest pixel values (max NDVIs) to one image
var composite = NDVI_S2.filterDate('2018-04-01','2018-04-15').qualityMosaic('NDVI')
  .addBands(NDVI_S2.filterDate('2018-04-16','2018-04-30').qualityMosaic('NDVI'))
  .addBands(NDVI_S2.filterDate('2018-05-01','2018-05-15').qualityMosaic('NDVI'))
  .addBands(NDVI_S2.filterDate('2018-05-16','2018-05-23').qualityMosaic('NDVI'))
  .addBands(NDVI_S2.filterDate('2018-06-01','2018-06-15').qualityMosaic('NDVI'))
  .addBands(NDVI_S2.filterDate('2018-06-16','2018-06-30').qualityMosaic('NDVI'))
  .addBands(NDVI_S2.filterDate('2018-07-01','2018-07-15').qualityMosaic('NDVI'))
  .addBands(NDVI_S2.filterDate('2018-07-16','2018-07-31').qualityMosaic('NDVI'))
  .addBands(NDVI_S2.filterDate('2018-08-01','2018-08-15').qualityMosaic('NDVI'))
  .addBands(NDVI_S2.filterDate('2018-08-16','2018-08-31').qualityMosaic('NDVI'))
  .addBands(NDVI_S2.filterDate('2018-09-01','2018-09-15').qualityMosaic('NDVI'))
  .addBands(NDVI_S2.filterDate('2018-09-16','2018-09-30').qualityMosaic('NDVI'))
  .addBands(NDVI_S2.filterDate('2018-10-01','2018-10-15').qualityMosaic('NDVI'))
  .addBands(NDVI_S2.filterDate('2018-10-16','2018-10-31').qualityMosaic('NDVI'));

//print(composite, 'composite')

// clip imagery to all regions and assign a variable each
var LVha1 = composite.clip(roi.filter(ee.Filter.eq('Region', 'LVha-1'))).set({region:"LVha-1"});
var LVha2 = composite.clip(roi.filter(ee.Filter.eq('Region', 'LVha-2'))).set({region:"LVha-2"});


//print(LVha1, 'LVha1')

//====================================================================
// import training/test data

var label = "class";
var bands = ['NDVI', 'NDVI_1','NDVI_2','NDVI_3','NDVI_4','NDVI_5','NDVI_6','NDVI_7', 'NDVI_8','NDVI_9', 'NDVI_10', 'NDVI_11', 'NDVI_12', 'NDVI_13'];

// Training data 

var imageList = ee.List([LVha1,LVha2]); 

// function to access training data from featureCollection for each region separately
function pixels(img){
  return img.sampleRegions({
    collection: training.filter(ee.Filter.eq("region",img.get("region"))),
    properties:["class", "region"],
    scale:10 
  })
}

// Mapping the function to all "greenest pixel" images -- Source: Oliver Lopez Stackexchange
var N = imageList.size();
var s = ee.List.sequence(0,N.subtract(1));

var results = ee.FeatureCollection(s.map(function(n){
 return pixels(ee.Image(imageList.get(n)));
}
)).flatten();


//assign training and test data

// assign random number to each training sample (separated by regions)
function assignData(regionName) {
  var region = results.filterMetadata("region", "equals", regionName)
  return results.filter(ee.Filter.eq('region', regionName)).randomColumn();
}

var LVha1_assign = assignData('LVha-1');
var LVha2_assign = assignData('LVha-2');

//print(LVha1_assign, 'LVha1_assign')

// recombining featureCollections to one FC
var featureList = LVha1_assign
    .merge(LVha2_assign);

// assign training data
function trainingData(regionName) {
  var region_assigned = featureList.filterMetadata("region", "equals", regionName)
  return region_assigned.filter(ee.Filter.lessThan('random', 0.8));
}

var LVha1_train = trainingData('LVha-1')
var LVha2_train = trainingData('LVha-2')


//print(LVha1_train, 'test train')


// assign test data 
function testData(regionName) {
  var region_assigned = featureList.filterMetadata("region", "equals", regionName)
  return region_assigned.filter(ee.Filter.greaterThanOrEquals('random', 0.8));
}

var LVha1_test = testData('LVha-1')
var LVha2_test = testData('LVha-2')

//print(LVha1_test, 'test test')

var testList = LVha1_test
    .merge(LVha2_test);

//===========================================================================================
// Make a Random Forest classifier and train it.

// therefor creating a list of featureCollections
var trainList = LVha1_train
    .merge(LVha2_train);

// define function to train the classifiers
function classifier(regionName) { 
  var traindat_region = trainList.filterMetadata("region", "equals", regionName)
  return traindat_region = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(100)
    .train({
      features: traindat_region,
      classProperty: label,
      inputProperties: bands
    });
}
// train classifiers for each region
var LVha1_RF = classifier('LVha-1');
var LVha2_RF = classifier('LVha-2');


//========================================================================================
//classify the images

// classification with training from LVha-1
var classified_1to01 = LVha1.select(bands).classify(LVha1_RF);
var classified_1to02 = LVha2.select(bands).classify(LVha1_RF);

// Accuracy Assessment
function confusionMatrix1(regionName) {
  var testdat_region = testList.filterMetadata("region", "equals", regionName)
  return ee.ConfusionMatrix(testdat_region.classify(LVha1_RF).errorMatrix({
  actual: "class",
  predicted: "classification"
}));
}

var OA_1to1 = ee.Feature(confusionMatrix1('LVha-1').accuracy());
var OA_1to2 = ee.Feature(confusionMatrix1('LVha-2').accuracy());

print(OA_1to1)
print(OA_1to2)

// classification with training from LVha-2
var classified_2to01 = LVha1.select(bands).classify(LVha2_RF);
var classified_2to02 = LVha2.select(bands).classify(LVha2_RF);

// Accuracy Assessment
function confusionMatrix2(regionName) {
  var testdat_region = testList.filterMetadata("region", "equals", regionName)
  return ee.ConfusionMatrix(testdat_region.classify(LVha2_RF).errorMatrix({
  actual: "class",
  predicted: "classification"
}));
}

var OA_2to1 = ee.Feature(confusionMatrix2('LVha-1').accuracy());
var OA_2to2 = ee.Feature(confusionMatrix2('LVha-2').accuracy());

print(OA_2to1)
print(OA_2to2)
```

additionally here is a link to my working script:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/dc5d932c0a054fdc6d12f24cac1392f8